# Finding difference between columns in column group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I am using report builder to create a report showing a budget for a project. The dataset includes line items for both budget and projected. See below for example rows. I am using a matrix with column group to display budget and projected side by side as well as a row group to show section, category, etc. I need to have a variance column that subtracts projected from budget.

I have scoured the interwebs for solutions but nothing that has worked so far. I feel like there has to be  simple solution to this given it is something that could be done in a sql query with zero effort. Most solutions are assuming I have two separate fields, but these are dynamic fields pull out with the column group.

```
Dataset Row Samples
Type      Section  Cateogry Phase            Task             Total
Budget    Building Kitchen  Pre-Construction Cabinet Hardware $100 
Projected Building Kitchen  Pre-Construction Cabinet Hardware $220 

Report sample


           COL GROUP        This is the column i want
           Budget Projected Variance
+Buidling  $100   $220      -$120
+Kitchen  
+Pre-Con
```

EDIT: I tried the below solution without success and have already visited every link provided in the second answer. Maybe there is something I am missing, but I ended up just doing everything in the SQL query and not use Column groups. This is 100% the simplest solution. I am very surprised there is no easy way to reference individual columns in a column group. The below may work for others, but I just could not get them to work for me. Not sure why.

Comment: I think you got 2 good answers that solves the issue. if the issue is solved you have to accept an answer also you can upvote helpful answer. check the [tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional column inside the “Type” group (provided that this is the name of your column group). Set the *Column Visibility* to hide the column by an expression like

```
= IsNothing(Previous(Field!Type.Value, “Type”)
```

Calculate the values for that column as

```
= Previous(Sum(Fields!Total.Value), “Type”) – Sum(Fields!Total.Value)
```

That should calculate the difference between the values of the previous type and the current type, and
only show that column for the "Projected" type (when there *is* a previous type).

Answer (score 0):

On the matrix, you can use the group subtotals to achieve this, you only have to overwrite the `SUM` operation with an expression that subtract to values. There are many link mentioning how to do that or that can helps you:

- [How to add calculated column from dynamic columns to a matrix](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/be3e6d81-cd79-44cf-98e8-b23ef13afa36/how-to-add-calculated-column-from-dynamic-columns-to-a-matrix?forum=sqlreportingservices)
- [Adding subtotals to SSRS report tablix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237465/adding-subtotals-to-ssrs-report-tablix)
- [How to write Expression to subtract row Group SubTotals](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/edaba341-c2cc-41af-a0a5-0ffd13ceb840/how-to-write-expression-to-subtract-row-group-subtotals?forum=sqlreportingservices)
- [Reporting in SQL Server – Using calculated Expressions within reports](https://www.sqlshack.com/reporting-sql-server-using-calculated-expressions-within-reports/)